# Is SparseArray good for resource id keys?

Tags: java, android, sparse-matrix

Is it advisable to use a `SparseArray` when the integer keys are resources id's? Or is it aimed at keys with lower numbers?

Yes, I know the definition of `SparseArray`, and the compiler always issues a warning when one uses `ArrayList` with integer keys, advising to use `SparseArray`.
But maybe when `SparseArray` was defined, they had in mind an array where you do have elements, but not all of them.
In my case, I want to use Resource IDs as keys, which are, for those of you who had a pick at the generated `R.java` file, very big numbers only. So I though that it may not fit, not only the intention, but also the implementation of `SparseArray`.

Comment: if one of the answers below is correct, please accept it

Answer (score 1):

SparseArray is exactly for values which are of an unknown range.  So it seems to fit your need.

Answer (score 1):

in R.java the resrource ids are all integer so there is no problem using sparse array.

Answer (score 0):

**Do not use the `SparseArray` together with the Resourse IDs** as keys. `SparseArray`sorts keys in ascending order for efficient access. Since resource ids are generated automatically, you cannot guarantee their order within `SparseArray`. This means that when you iterate over the `SparseArray`, you will not follow the same order as you would when filling in the FW.

I think you should use LinkedHashMap instead.